# How to create inputbox which contains a list

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to select a value from a list in inputbox. Something like that:

```
Dim test As String
test = InputBox("Here I want to have a list")
```

I don't know how to do that. Or what should use instead of `InputBox`?

Comment: Create your custom Form and get whatever you want from user.

Comment: Suggestion : put a Panel(you can toggle visibility panel is more suitable for your case since you don't want to use a form) in your form and add textbox control on that panel load the text box with the AutoCompleteStringCollection or try work outing to make _custom inputbox_ from [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103846-custom-inputbox/) you can start

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListBox control which is available in .NET

This article might be useful for you. 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/how-to-move-listitems-from-one-listbox.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes i also suggest ListBox Control....
Please read below Article on ListBox Control:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/listbox-control-in-asp-net3/

So that you can understand why we suggest ListBox Control.

Comment: How this be an answer? post such suggestions in comment

Comment: Ok I know about `ListBox` control, but I don't want to open a new Form with `ListBox`. I just need something like `InputBox`. Can I add a list to `inputbox`? This code is just a simple example to show you want I want.

Comment: @XardasLord An InputBox is limited to what you get. You will have to make your own Form with a ComboBox on it. I'm not sure why people are suggesting ASP.NET options.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a ComboBox which is designed to select an item and display it in a separate area.  Put it in a Modal Form and you can replicate what you get from an InputBox.